# modalPresentationStyle default value in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

As per apple documentation,

> The default value for this property is UIModalPresentationStyle.automatic

In iOS 12, the default value was UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen, and that what I get.

But when I am running my app on iOS 13 I am getting `.pageSheet as navigationController.modalPresentationStyle`

Is there anything I am doing wrong or the default value is .pageSheet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **UIModalPresentationStyle.automatic** switches between **.pageSheet** and **.fullScreen** depending on the context in which **UIViewController** is presented.
2. If you are using normal **UIViewController** it will default to **.pageSheet**.
3. But if you are using some subclass of **UIViewController** like **UIImagePickerController** iOS expects content should in full screen mode so it will default to **.fullscreen**.
4. If you are using **iOS** version less than **13** it will always default to **.fullscreen**.

Answer (score 1):

Presentation style is Automatic which defaults to pagesheet in iOS 13 when you present a viewcontroller modally

Answer (score 1):

> The default presentation style chosen by the system. It's
>   **`UIModalPresentationAutomatic`**

Automatic means if we using `UIImagePickerController` and sourceType `.photoLibrary` then it's present as cascade view. And sourceType `.camera` then it's present in full screen.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/uimodalpresentationpagesheet?language=objc